# Which phrases to use to describe two groups?

Tags: word-choice

I need help to describe two Groups in a precise way. 
Group 1 has been a part of a treatment program for some (nonspecific)time, and Group 2 has just recently joined this treatment program. 
Both of these two Groups have now been enrolled in a study. 
Group 1 is so to say established in the treatment program. Group 2 has joined the program mainly to be able to take part in the study. 
How can these two Groups be described precisely in short form, when the purpose is to define their Connection With the treatment program prior to the study participation. 
Grateful for help!

Comment: Group 1 could be referred to as "an experienced group", and Group 2 could be referred to as "an inexperienced group" or "a beginners group" maybe...?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to two different groups, the words "former" and "latter" could be of use. **Former** means the one that **came before**. **Latter** refers to the second of two mentioned subjects (according to Dictionary.com).

If you establish that Group 1 came first, you can refer to it as the former group.

> The **former** group has been a part of the program for a while...

And by default, Group 2 will be the latter group.

> ...while the **latter** had just joined the program.

I would like to note that the terms "former" and "latter" really only work as far as comparison goes.  If you're not comparing them constantly, it would be better to give them names, which would really be up to you.  Group 1, as far as you've described it, could be "the established group" while Group 2 could be "the recent group".